# Getting bounds in result with width_bucket

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do a query using `width_bucket` and having a column in the results with the bounds of my buckets. Is there a simple way to do this?

My query:

```
SELECT width_bucket(
            (EXTRACT(epoch FROM S.end - S.start) / 60)::integer, 
            array[0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 1000]
       ) AS buckets,
       count(*)
FROM shipments_site S
WHERE S.deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY buckets
ORDER BY buckets
```

Result:

```
buckets | count
1       | 20
2       | 6
3       | 22
4       | 25
5       | 10
6       | 11
7       | 6
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
buckets | count    | interval
1       | 20       | [0, 15]
2       | 6        | [15, 30]
3       | 22       | [30, 45]
4       | 25       | [45, 60]
5       | 10       | [60, 75]
6       | 11       | [75, 90]
7       | 6        | [90, 1000]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a fixed sets of buckets, another option is to join against a list of ranges:

```
with buckets (bucket) as (
  values 
     (int4range(0,15)),
     (int4range(15,30)),
     (int4range(30,45)),
     (int4range(45,60)),
     (int4range(60,75)),
     (int4range(75,90)),
     (int4range(90,null)
  )
) 
SELECT b.bucket, count(*)
FROM shipments_site S
  JOIN buckets b on (extract(epoch from "end" - start) / 60)::int <@ b.bucket
WHERE S.deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY b.bucket
ORDER BY b.bucket;
```

Comment: Elegant solution! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT v.bucket, count(*),
       CONCAT( (array[0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 1000])[v.bucket], '-',
               (array[0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 1000])[v.bucket + 1]
             ) as bounds
FROM shipments_site S CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (width_bucket((EXTRACT(epoch FROM S.end - S.start) / 60)::integer, 
                           array[0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 1000]
                          )
             )
     ) v(bucket)
WHERE S.deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY v.bucket
ORDER BY v.bucket;
```

The idea is to use a lateral join to define the `bucket`.  Then just index the bucket in the array to get the bounds.

If you don't want to repeat the array, you can include it in the `FROM` clause as well:

```
SELECT v.bucket, count(*),
       CONCAT( (v_ar.ar_bounds)[v.bucket], '-',
               (v_ar.ar_bounds)[v.bucket + 1]
             ) as bounds
FROM shipments_site S CROSS JOIN
     (values (array[0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 1000])
     ) v_ar(ar_bounds) CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (width_bucket((EXTRACT(epoch FROM S.end - S.start) / 60)::integer, 
                           v_ar.ar_bounds
                          )
             )
     ) v(bucket)
WHERE S.deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY v.bucket, v_ar.ar_bounds
ORDER BY v.bucket;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a3f43dc22e8fede88e2f0bcdfe4afec8) is a db<>fiddle.